# How to integrate one Python library into another?

Tags: python, privacy, pandas-profiling

I have to integrate PyDP into Pandas Profiling. The purpose of this integration is to bring Differential Privacy into Pandas Profiling so that the EDA summary that we would get be differentially private.

The idea is simple -> to replace the mean function used in Pandas Profiling with the private mean in the PyDP package.

Comment: Could probably do something fancy with a monkey patch. I'd start my research there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.